# Weird Strings When using Asci chars

Tags: php, string, compression

```
$txt = $_POST['name'];// in firefox I can see 0© when a post is made = correct

// then the weird part begins

// page encoding  = utf 8

var_dump($txt); // string '0©' (length=3)

var_dump(  '0©' )  ;

string '0�' (length=2)
```

1. why they have different length, both are strings, somehow the © entities is taking 2 chars on  the post request.
2. why the first one is displayed corectly and the second no
3. How can this be solved?

I'm creating an compression alghorithm for strings and I need asci chars not html entities.

Comment: Your code document isn't in UTF-8. I have got this response: `string(3) "0©"`

Comment: Also http://3v4l.org/QDlMR

Comment: Could it be that you are _not_ using the mbstring overloading feature in your php configuration? Then obviously you will get wrong string length reported on utf sequences (multibyte characters).

Comment: maybe you can `$txt = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['name'], 'utf-8');`

Comment: Set your editor to save in UTF-8, no BOM.

Comment: @fiction the document encoding is utf-8 so is have nothing to do with file encoding.

Comment: @Eugen it didn't solved the problem. as I said if  I type var_dump('0©') I get  length =2 if I get the string in the same file from post I get length=3 and the character is showing up perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So  I went back a bit and guess that the  © is taking 2 chars.

Then I              var_dump(substr('0©',1,2)); and I confirmed my suspicion.

The problem was that I was croping the string with substr('0©',i,2);

Problem solved.

$letter = mb_substr($text,$i,2,'UTF-8'); solved my problem